# Postfix on CentOS 6.6 is overwriting my return-path header?

Tags: centos, php, email, postfix

I'm [dealing](https://turbolab.it/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3861) with this problem on my CentOS 6.6 server: when I send a mail with PHP/phpBB ([mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function), **Postfix overwrites the return path with apache@servername**.

The issue is also expained in [this phpBB bug report](https://tracker.phpbb.com/browse/PHPBB3-10027). The only way I [found](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2101814#p14100721) to deal with the issue is to patch the application and force a `-f my.desidere.return-path@example.com`.

The phpBB team [said](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2101814) is a server issue, but I don't know where to start.

I've a default CentOS 6.6 installation (Postfix) + OpenDKIM (but I suspect the latter is not relevant).

Any hints?

Comment: Post the output of `postconf -n`

Comment: And the maillog entry when phpBB send emails

Comment: Just to be clear: Does phpBB include envelope sender (`-f` appended to email) in the last argument ("additional_parameters") of the `mail()` function? Ie: `-fuser@example.com`

Comment: @dhaupin no, it doesn't use any -f option at all (see the link I provided in my question)

Comment: Ah i see now in the forum post. Just wasn't sure if they patched it yet, or if your serv was still doing the same thing after you added `"-f" . $config['board_email']`. I stumbled on this Q because our serv was doing something similar even with -f set, but come to find out the multi-domain platform had instantiated mail class for contact form that was overriding using a static email instead of per-domain emails that were called deeper in. In PhpBB case, it's a super simple fix for a bug 5 years old. So noob they haven't patched it by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local submission via filesocket do not suppose any authentification, so return path is constructed as `active UID` @ `hostname`. You have to setup your PHP-mailer to use `hostname` as SMTP host instead of `localhost` for complete SMTP-session with `MAIL FROM:` command.